# Video.js doesn't work in FF, IE

Tags: javascript, mp4, video.js

This works fine in Chrome and Opera, but not in Firefox and IE. 
I don't know the problem, I have no errors in console.
After clicking on Play button there is nothing happend (play button disappears and thats all).

Style:

```
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-playtoggle-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-progress-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-controls,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-time-divider,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-captions-button,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-volume-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-play-control,
.vjs-default-skin .vjs-fullscreen-control {
    display: none;  
}
.vjs-control-bar {
visibility: visible !important;
opacity: 1 !important;
transition-duration: 0s!important;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id='container'>
    <video id='movie_container' class='video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered' data-setup='{}' preload='none' controls height='360px' width='640px'>
    </video>
</div>
```

JS

```
_V_.options.flash.params = {
           allowfullscreen: "true",
           wmode: "transparent",
           allowscriptaccess: "always"
       };
var videojs_player;
window.player = videojs("movie_container", { techOrder: ["flash", "html5"] }, function() {
    videojs_player = this;
    videojs_player.src({ src: "http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4", type: 'video/mp4'})
    videojs_player.pause = function() {};

    function myFunc()
    {
        //finish
    }
    function myFunc2()
    {
        //start
    }
    videojs_player.on('ended',myFunc);      
    videojs_player.on('play',myFunc2);
});
```

Comment: If you could set up a live, reduced test case, it would help solve this issue. You can use this jsbin as a starting point: http://jsbin.com/axedog/edit?html,output

Also it looks like you're using an old version of video.js (_V_ is deprecated). You might try upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `data-setup='{}'` from the Video element. You shouldn't include that if using the alternate setup. Video (or audio) elements with a `data-setup` attribute are automatically set up as video.js players, it's likely just a difference in browser timing that on Firefox and IE the player has already been created when you call `videojs()`, but in Chrome and Opera it has not been.